# на сервере выдает ошибку error 145 hy000

Tags: linux, debian

Сервер debian 7 выдает ошибку:

> "error 145 (hy000) at line 1: Table ./admin/p7u9t_session is marked as
>   crashed  and should be repaired"

и дальше 15 строк кода

> "error 23 (hy000) at line 1: out of resources when opening file
>   ./admin/p7u9t_viruemart_*.MYD (errcode:24)"

Где звездочка там в каждой строке другой имя файла. пробовал переустанавливать базу не помогло. Возможно(скорее всего) что то не так сделал.

Comment: база - MySQL? или что то другое

Comment: покажите вывод `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'open%'`

Answer (score 1):

Error 23 указывает на то, что превышено количество файлов, которое может открывать mysql.
Посмотреть и отредактировать (добавить) данный параметр можно в файле конфигурации mysql */etc/my.cnf* и перезапустить сервер

`[mysqld]
open_files_limit = 5000`

Затем перейдите к ошибке 145 указывающий на краш таблицы. Если есть phpmyadmin, то можно попытаться сделать восстановление таблицы через админку. Если нет, пробуйте:

```
mysqlcheck -uroot -ppassword --auto-repair --check --optimize --all-databases
```